# How to create url with complex query

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I use dart and flutter for mobile app. I use my api to get data from server. But I found a problem, maybe its dart core problem.

I need to add complex queryParams to my URL like

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>{"a": {"b": ["c","d"]}, "e": {}}
```

I use `Uri.parse(url).replace(queryParams: myQueryParams).toString()`

But  `Uri.replace()` accepts only `Map<String, Iterable<String>>` and throws an error

`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

I found method which throws this error

```
  static String _makeQuery(String query, int start, int end,
      Map<String, dynamic /*String|Iterable<String>*/ > queryParameters) {
    if (query != null) {
      if (queryParameters != null) {
        throw ArgumentError('Both query and queryParameters specified');
      }
      return _normalizeOrSubstring(query, start, end, _queryCharTable,
          escapeDelimiters: true);
    }
    if (queryParameters == null) return null;

    var result = StringBuffer();
    var separator = "";

    void writeParameter(String key, String value) {
      result.write(separator);
      separator = "&";
      result.write(Uri.encodeQueryComponent(key));
      if (value != null && value.isNotEmpty) {
        result.write("=");
        result.write(Uri.encodeQueryComponent(value));
      }
    }

    queryParameters.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == null || value is String) {
        writeParameter(key, value);
      } else {
        Iterable values = value;
        for (String value in values) {
          writeParameter(key, value);
        }
      }
    });
    return result.toString();
  }
```

So my question is there is some method in dart to add my queryParams to url or I need to create it by my own?

Comment: What URL query string would you expect that to turn into? `a=something&e=something_else`? Please fill in the gaps.

Comment: @RichardHeap something like this `?options[option_volume][]=30ml&options[option_volume][]=60ml&attributes[attribute_color_shade][]=brown&attributes[attribute_producer][]=worldfamous`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified original method and now its work.

```
class UrlCreator {
  static String addQueryParams(String url, Map<String, dynamic> queryParams) {
    var result = StringBuffer();
    var separator = "";

    void writeParameter(String key, String value) {
      result.write(separator);
      separator = "&";
      result.write(Uri.encodeQueryComponent(key));
      if (value != null && value.isNotEmpty) {
        result.write("=");
        result.write(Uri.encodeQueryComponent(value));
      }
    }

    void buildQuery(Map queryParams, {parentKey}){
      queryParams.forEach((key, value){
        print("parentKey = $parentKey Key = $key value = $value");
        if (value == null || value is String) {
          var newKey = parentKey != null ? "$parentKey[$key]" : key;
          writeParameter(newKey, value);
        } else if (value is Map) {
          buildQuery(value, parentKey: key);
        } else {
          Iterable values = value;
          var newKey = parentKey != null ? "$parentKey[$key][]" : "$key[]";
          for (String value in values) {
            writeParameter(newKey, value);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    buildQuery(queryParams);

    return url + "?" + result.toString();
  }
}
```